# How can I change MTP to PTP with a broken screen?

Tags: samsung, settings, usb

I have little to no access to my phone's screen. It is a Samsung Galaxy J3 Prime and I want to transfer my files on a computer but it wont show up my files. HOwever, I'm sure its because the usb settings are at MTP. I've heard of Smart Dock and something called an OP, what are those things? I've also heard of debugging, but not sure I understand it well enough to try to use it. So could I use any of these ways and how do they work?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to get an OTG adapter and connect a USB mouse to your phone. You can then use the mouse to control your phone.